# Solana Wallet verification failing?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, wallet, solana

Hope fully someone can better explain this to me but  am fairly new to Solana.  I have setup a new wallet.  I run the following commands below. When I run the last command Solana-keygen  verify. It fails. Why is this?

````
keypair file itself, which is stored as insecure plain text

BIP39 Passphrase (empty for none):

====================================================================================
pubkey: At4PCqTxBw3qkfb8ThQgMsc6yuq6SC7mNr8m9gmwk7zC
====================================================================================
Save this seed phrase and your BIP39 passphrase to recover your new keypair:
road leader toilet awful mixed cupboard tragic prepare kingdom glow imitate category
==================================================================================== ```

I run the following commands: 
```PS C:\Users\isiah\OneDrive\Desktop\Solana> solana-keygen pubkey prompt://
[pubkey recovery] seed phrase: 
[pubkey recovery] If this seed phrase has an associated passphrase, enter it now. Otherwise, press ENTER to continue: 
4QChrvQC4UDcgQCHbd5JxWBBSUW8JaP8rJcKZ2fiiAno
PS C:\Users\isiah\OneDrive\Desktop\Solana>

PS C:\Users\isiah\OneDrive\Desktop\Solana> solana-keygen pubkey ASK
[pubkey recovery] seed phrase: 
[pubkey recovery] If this seed phrase has an associated passphrase, enter it now. Otherwise, press ENTER to continue: 
At4PCqTxBw3qkfb8ThQgMsc6yuq6SC7mNr8m9gmwk7zC

Solana-keygen verify At4PCqTxBw3qkfb8ThQgMsc6yuq6SC7mNr8m9gmwk7zC prompt://
[pubkey recovery] seed phrase: 
[pubkey recovery] If this seed phrase has an associated passphrase, enter it now. Otherwise, press ENTER to continue: 
Verification for public key: At4PCqTxBw3qkfb8ThQgMsc6yuq6SC7mNr8m9gmwk7zC: Failed
````

Answer (score 2):

Does it work if you enter below?

```
solana-keygen verify 4QChrvQC4UDcgQCHbd5JxWBBSUW8JaP8rJcKZ2fiiAno prompt://
```

I think the problem is because you are verifying the public key output from solana-keygen ASK instead of the one from solana-keygen pubkey prompt://, which give you raw ed25519 keypair pubkey. In fact, if you create a keypair from wallet, it normally give you a public key with derivation path m/44'/501'.

Comment: It Worked! Thank you. DO you know why we have to verify the raw pubkey instead of the one that we use when we run Solana-keygen pukey prompt:// ?

Comment: It is because the algorithm it used. Running the one output from solana-keygen ASK is a raw ed25519 keypair pub key. However, in most wallet out there, the pub keys are not generated this way. Instead, they put a derivation path like m/44'/501' in it. That's the same way how you generated using Solana-keygen pukey prompt://.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it works. It helps others with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is the equivalent of verify command from CLI but in web3.js solana SDK? 

I’m testing with isOnCurve but this don’t ensure that an address is valid in an specific environment or cluster